# Is there a way to translate strings from one language to another using python for free without a daily limit?

Tags: python, translation

I am making a web scraper where i need to translate words from english to dutch.
I am currently using this module: https://pypi.org/project/translate/. After a while I run out of free daily translations. Is there a way to do this for free, possibly locally or using a different method?

Comment: use a different module

Comment: @Evorage do you know a module that could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if Google Translate limits the number of daily translations you can make - I know that through their official API, you need an API key, and it's probably limited - but what about the API your browser talks to when you translate something via Google search?

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single"

    english_sentence = "I am hungry"
    from_language = "en"
    to_language = "de"

    params = {
        "client": "webapp",
        "sl": "auto",
        "tl": to_language,
        "hl": from_language,
        "dt": "t",
        "tk": "374347.226425",
        "q": english_sentence
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    data = response.json()

    german_sentence = data[0][0][0]

    print(german_sentence)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Ich bin hungrig
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i will try this out!